# Problem with Springer latex template SVJour3 f

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, latex, journal

my springer manuscript works fine on overleaf, but when building pdf for review submission I get errors. I don't know how to fix this.
Could you please help me?

''''

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}

\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath} ``
\usepackage{doi}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

''''
My log file https://1drv.ms/b/s!Ajv_KLtup0whaZa_nx-6MCIkpo0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a forbidden character on page 7 in the sentence

```
.... volves a subset of variables and specifies the allowable ...
```

The fi in "specifies" is a ligature which is not allowed in pdflatex. Delete it and retype it as `fi`